# "You are on a branch yet to be born" when adding git submodule

Tags: git, git-submodules

I am attempting to add a few submodules to my `.vim/bundles` directory, and when I attempt to add this particular repo Git gives me a strange error I've never seen before:

```
$ git submodule add -f git://github.com/derekwyatt/vim-scala.git .vim/bundle/vim-scala
fatal: You are on a branch yet to be born
Unable to checkout submodule '.vim/bundle/vim-scala'
```

Any idea what can cause this?

If I clone the same repo to a test directory (not through the submodule command), it works fine, and creates the expected files.

Answer (score 232, accepted):

To fix that error, you should delete the folder with the same path to the submodule inside `.git/modules/` directory. This error can occurs when url was incorrect for submodule for the first-time when submodule was added.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. Was a bit non-obvious at first that since I was cloning to `.vim/bundle/vim-scala` the path to delete was `.git/modules/.vim/bundle/vim-scala`

Comment: If you're on windows note that the directory under .git/modules may not show up unless you `dir /AH`

Comment: After I see delete that `.git/modules/path/to/submodule` directory and try to re-add the submodule, I receive the error _The following path is ignored by one of your .gitignore files: path/to/submodule_.

Comment: @Drew Noakes remove .vim/bundle/vim-scala created after first run of git submodule add

Comment: On windows you can also use the Windows Explorer options (in the same place you would choose to see file extensions) to see the hidden folders in the GUI and delete them.

Comment: If this the parent submodule is a submodule itself, the .git directory will be of the root module (the submodules will only have a .git file, not a directory).

Comment: same result after deleting modules dir from .git and the dir created in parent project. Why should it be any different than when it failed the first time and those dirs were not there yet?

Comment: If you are adding a submodule that consists of a shiny new empty repo like I was, you will go in circles until you do a commit to master (like a readme.md,) in addition to the removal of the directory mentioned here. The "branch yet to be born" is master.

Comment: This, **together with Useless'** answer solved my problem. An ideal answer would be a combination of both. Thanks!

Answer (score 22):

This error can happen if you are adding a submodule which doesn't have a `master` branch. If you want to use another branch when adding the submodule (`develop` for instance), you can use the following command:

```
git submodule add -b <branch> <repository>
```

Comment: In my case repo was newly created and therefore didn't have any files and branches (was empty), so `git submodule add -b master <repo.git> <folder>` helped

Comment: This was my problem my submodule had only 2 branches none of them is a `master` your solution worked for me.

Answer (score 13):

You need to add a submodule *inside* an existing repo, that repo needs to be in a state to add & commit the submodule link, *and* the submodule repo itself must have a commit to check out.

Now, the submodule repo itself must be ok if you can create a regular clone elsewhere. However, it looks like `submodule add` complains if the repo is empty while clone does not. [This guy](http://chee-yang.blogspot.co.uk/2011/07/git-submodule.html) suggests this is fixable by just running the same `submodule add` command again.

If the inner repo is *not* empty, check the repo you want to *contain* the submodule. Change to the same directory where you ran `git submodule add`, and run `git status`, and `git branch` to verify that your containing repo has at least one branch created and isn't in a weird state.

Comment: I've verified all of these things. When I check out the desired repo to another directory, it has many files, and a `master` branch. The repo I am trying to add this one to as a submodule is on the `master` branch, has no obvious problems (status returns some modified files, but that's all), and weirdest of all is that I can add other submodules just fine to this repository.

Comment: Also odd: after the `fatal` warning from my OP, git leaves an empty dir at `.vim/bundle/vim-scala`. I also noticed that even though `.gitmodules` is untouched, it added some lines referring to this github.com repo to `.git/config`, but after removing those I still get the same `fatal` error message.

Comment: +1 Argh! `This guy suggests this is fixable by just running the same submodule add command again.`. I've been battling this problem trying to find a sensible answer and this finally fixed it. This was for git 1.8.0 under MSYS while creating a submodule from BitBucket, so if you're in the same situation, try this first.

Comment: Adding twice worked for me, too. But I don't understand why. Any explanation?

Comment: Adding twice here as well. I would love to understand why though

Comment: Probably because `git submodule add` is a compound operation: (clone if necessary and checkout the correct branch) and then add. On the first run, the clone succeeds but the checkout fails because there is no commit to find, yet.

Answer (score 0):

As alluded to by @drew-noakes, this can be caused by attempting to add a submodule using a directory name that is listed in your *.gitignore* file.